# Prevent multiple event handling in Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal for multiple actions like "Add user" or "Edit user". Every time I click a button it opens the modal for me and I can fill in the fields and submit.
But if I click the first button, then the second button and then the first button again, it sends me the post 3x in a row. So it creates a new event listener for me each time.

If I remove the event listener in the resetModal() function, then it sends me the POST only once each time, but then the buttons don't go on the second click and console.log(state, 'state') remains empty. Exactly the same behavior if I give the AddEventListener "once: true".
So I can only have one behavior. Either the buttons work on every click and data-state etc is passed, or it only sends me one POST per submit.
How can I make it so that both things work?

I have a very simplified JSFiddle to try around with: https://jsfiddle.net/dvkyjtbz/1/

```js
const exampleModal = document.querySelector('#exampleModal');
let isEventListenerAttached = false;

function resetModal(event) {
  const modalForm = event.currentTarget.querySelector('form');

  if (modalForm) {
    modalForm.reset();
  }
  
  // Remove to run RemoveEventListener
  // exampleModal.removeEventListener('show.bs.modal', handleUserModal);
}

function saveUserData(user, state) {
  const {
    title,
    body,
    userId,
  } = user;
  const url = (userId) ? `/${userId}` : '';
  const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(exampleModal);

  axios({
      method: (userId) ? 'put' : 'post',
      url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts${url}`,
      data: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
        userId: userId,
      },
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Success!')
      modal.hide();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

function handleSubmit(event, modal, state, userID) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const modalTitle = modal.querySelector('.modal-body #title');
  const modalBody = modal.querySelector('.modal-body #body');

  saveUserData({
    title: modalTitle.value,
    body: modalBody.value,
    userId: (state === 'newUser') ? '' : userID,
  }, state);
}

function handleUserModal(event) {
  if (isEventListenerAttached) {
    return;
  }

  const button = event.relatedTarget;
  const state = button.getAttribute('data-state') || 'newUser';
  const userID = button.getAttribute('data-uid');
  const modal = event.currentTarget;
  const saveUserButton = modal.querySelector('[form-submit="useradministration-save-user"]');
  const title = (state === 'newUser') ? 'Add New User' : 'Edit User';
  const modalTitle = modal.querySelector('.modal-title');
  
  if (modalTitle) {
    modalTitle.textContent = title;
  }
  
  console.log(state, 'state')

  saveUserButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    handleSubmit(event, modal, state, userID);
  });
}

exampleModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', handleUserModal);
exampleModal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', resetModal);
```